# Why is C stdout not returning "ls" command content?

Tags: c, terminal, stdout, popen

I have been working on a reverse shell (not for malicious uses) and have started to learn how to use the popen function and get the output using stdout. I have started to test it out, and it was working fine, until I tried using the terminal command "ls". Could anyone point out (what I'm assuming is) my error and show me how to fix it?

Here is the code for the C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    while (1){
        char* command = (char *) malloc(15*sizeof(char));
        char* output = (char *) malloc(2048);
        printf(">> ");
        scanf("%s", command);
        FILE* cmd = popen(command, "r");
        fputs(output, stdout);
        pclose(cmd);
        if (strlen(output) != 0){
            printf("\n%s\n", output);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the code for the input I've provided the program, and it's result:

```
>> cd /Users/
sh: /Users/: is a directory //output from previous command
>> >> ls                    //also why did the program print '>>' twice?
>>
```

Another question: Why did the program print `>>` twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code appears to be missing the connection between `popen()` (really `cmd`) and the `output` variable.  You could for example use `fread()` to read from the `cmd` "file" into `output`.

---

Calling `scanf("%s", ...)` will scan only one whitespace-separated word at a time.  Your program is first running `cd`, then on the next iteration it is running `/Users/`.

---

The code is leaking memory by repeatedly allocating buffers `command` and `output` in the `while` loop without `free`-ing them.

Comment: How can I connect popen and the output variable?

Comment: See above in the answer:  You could for example use `fread()` to read from the `cmd` "file" into `output`.